# What is the way to undo Object -> Scale -> Apply, so I can see the actual dimensions of an object, and not (1,1,1)?

Tags: transforms, dimensions, measurement

I'm working through the book [Blender 3D By Example, Second Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/product/blender-3d-by-example-second-edition/9781789612561). The second major project is a "time machine". One set of steps is to set the scale for objects to 1,1,1. The author states that "All finished models should have a scale of 1,1,1." (page 111).

However, I'm learning, and I'd like to know the actual dimensions of the objects so I can create it myself. What is the way to undo Object -> Apply -> Scale? Or is there some other way to show the actual dimensions of objects after the Object -> Apply -> Scale -> Transformation has been applied, so I can know the actual dimensions and learn to create that myself?

The finished model is:

https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Blender-3D-By-Example-Second-Edition/blob/master/Blender3DByExample_Chapter03-04/TimeMachine_End.blend

Comment: While in object mode the 3d viewport properties "N" item tab contains the dimension based on a bounding box.

Comment: The "actual dimensions" are visible in the 3D View properties sidebar. Press N in the 3D View to show it, and look towards the bottom. AFAIK you cannot undo a scale apply, unless you undo all the steps after it.

Comment: Your question has been answered already.  Small Addition.  Blender has a measuring tool on screen for casual measurements.  I might use the tool within the bounding box. Suggestion.  Please Press T and see the item measuring tool.